# Where can I find "Risk Express" dice?

Tags: dice, risk-express

*Risk Express* (or *Age of War* if you prefer) is a great game and I'd like to create my own version. That's easy, the game contains just a bunch of cards and 8 dice. I'm interested in such dice, they are six sided, but have army symbols (a cannon, a dragoon(?), musketeers e.t.c.) instead of numbers.

Where can I find such dice? Not necessarily with the same symbols, anything war related may do, I'll re-theme the game anyway, no sci-fi or modern guns though, I want to keep it in ancient, medieval or Napoleonic age. I searched a lot in dice shops but found nothing...

Comment: Maybe contact the manufacturer, sometimes they sell replacement parts.

Comment: @8odoros What exactly is it about the dice that you want? The shape? Some combination of symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the BoardGameGeek Store, they sell an item called ["Rattlebones" Prototyping Dice](http://boardgamegeekstore.com/products/rattlebones-prototyping-dice). These dice have snap-on faces so you can changes how many times a given colour face appears on each, and in addition you can draw symbols on those faces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are computer handy, you can build your own program and graphics to simulate the dice throws.

This assumes that you don't mind losing the tactile feedback from rolling the dice.

This is what I did when playing dice intensive games such as Warhammer 40,000.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to obtain the dice. To name a few:

- The easiest way is to buy the game.
- If you want the same dice but you don't want to buy the game you can contact the manufacturer. Sometimes, they sell replacement parts.
- You can make custom dice, which is probably expensive.

Comment: Any dice with battle/unit symbols may do, I'm not picky. I don't necessarily want to get the same dice.

Answer (score 0):

You could just get blank dice and draw on them. If you google "blank dice" you should get tons of offers for quite cheap.

Answer (score -1):

You can get Chessex.com to make custom Risk dice for you as I have.